# How to set the background of an ellipse in javascript to an image?

Tags: javascript, html, image, p5.js

I'm using javascript with the p5 library and currently I only know how to use the fill() function to fill an ellipse with a color. Is there a way to set the ellipse's background to an image?

Answer (score 2):

Rather that *setting a background* you could try using the [mask()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Image/mask) method combined with the [ellipse()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/ellipse) method:

```js
let photo, maskImage

function preload() {
  photo = loadImage('https://picsum.photos/300/200')
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 200)
  background(125)
  image(photo, 0, 0);
  maskImage = createGraphics(300, 200)
  maskImage.ellipse(150, 100, 250, 150)
  photo.mask(maskImage)
  image(photo, 300, 0)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```